# notepad++ regular expression search failed

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try using the following to search some text and replace it by some other text starts with #.
On regex101 it works fine but NotePad++ says search failed.
Also tried to add \r before \n but didn't help.

regex: `(class boy(?:.*\n)+\s*)(Height.*;\n)((?:.*\n)+})`

Text to search:

```
class boy Mike
{
Age = 20;
PhoneNum = 658965;
Height = 198;
City = LA
}
note boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
Height = 178;
City = BA
}

class boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
Height = 178;
City = BA
}
```

Substitute:
`$1#$2$3`

Output:

```
class boy Mike
{
Age = 20;
PhoneNum = 658965;
#Height = 198;
City = LA
}
note boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
Height = 178;
City = BA
}

class boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
#Height = 178;
City = BA
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**: `^class boy.*(?:\R(?!}$).*)*\R\K(?=Height)`
**Replace With**: `#`
**`.` matches newline**: DISABLED

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of line
- `class boy` - `class boy` and then any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `.*` - the rest of line
- `(?:\R(?!}$).*)*` - zero or more lines up to end of file or to a line that is equal to `}`
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\K` - omit the text matched
- `(?=Height)` - immediately on the right, there must be `Height`.

Comment: how can I see the CR LF?

Comment: @axcelenator *View* -> *Show Symbol* -> *Show All characters*.

Comment: If between classes I will add some other structure like this:```class boy Mike
{
Age = 20;
PhoneNum = 658965;
Height = 198;
City = LA
}

note boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
Height = 178;
City = BA
}

class boy Joe
{
Age = 21;
PhoneNum = 558565;
Height = 178;
City = BA
}```

Comment: @axcelenator I see. Your file only contains several `class`es?

Comment: Yes but every class has other name. I decribed the example by class but it contains also other names... Edited my post with new example

Comment: @axcelenator Updated, see the new solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative ...

Find;`^(class[\s\S]+?)(height)`

Replace all: `$1#$2`

[image]

Comment: `(?!note)(height)` is **always** true if `height` is present, the negative lookahead is useless here.

Comment: I didn't use lookahead here? It says find,  class everything till height. But except if starts with (note) and ends with height,,,,, another form of the same code is,  `^(class(?!note)[\s\S]+?)(height)` which gives the same result and meanings...

Comment: `(?!note)` **is** a lookahead.

Comment: `^(class(?!note)[\s\S]+?)(height)` prevents to match `classnote...` but not `class note....` See: https://regex101.com/r/wnjUIs/1

Comment: You are absolutely right (?!note) was completely useless .... `^(class[\s\S]+?)(height)` gave the same result..... I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten you regex so it doesn't use `newline`:

```
(?<=class boy \w+\s*\{[^}]+?)(Height[^;]+;)(?=[\s\S]+?\})
```

Use '**global**' and '**multiline**' options.

**Replace with:**

```
#$1
```

**Explanation**:

`(?<=class boy \w+\s*\{[^}]+?)` look behind for:`class boy`, a space and one or more word characters followed by one ore more white space (that includes newline). Then look for `{` followed by one or more characters not being `}`.

`(Height[^;]+;)` match 'Heigth' followed by one or more character not being `;` - put the match in group 1.

`(?=[\s\S]+?\})` look forward for any character followed by `}`.

Replace with `#` and group 1.